# Should we merge the [aura] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

It seems like the `[aura]` tag into one of the `[lightning]` tags. Do you guys agree? Which tag should be the master? Just `[lightning]`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `[lightning]` is typically used to refer to the lightning component/lightning application/lightning experience set of functionality, but we should be careful with merging into that tag since there is quite a few unrelated salesforce features that also use the "lightning" branding. A few that came to mind right away:

- [lightning connect](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Connect) (Although this was later renamed "Salesforce Connect")
- [lightning process builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Process_Builder)
- lightning for [gmail](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_sales_lightning_for_gmail.htm) or [outlook](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/06/introducing-lightning-for-outlook.html)
- [lightning sync](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_sales_lightning_sync.htm)

---

I like `[aura]` as it's own separate tag, but I think that people are misusing it too much. I think it's tempting to want to merge it because of how often people use this tag when they are referring to something else.

From the help text on the aura tag, [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/aura/info):

> The implementation of Aura on the Force.com Platform has now become
>   Lightning Components and Lightning App Builder, along with several
>   related features. For questions related to these, please do not use
>   the Aura tag. This should be reserved for the open source framework
>   only.

If people could stick to those guidelines, I don't think there would be such an issue.

Comment: But doesn't `aura` seem like it should be merged *somewhere*? I'm happy to leave it be, I'm just curious because I haven't spent a ton of time on this aspect of the platform.

Comment: I agree with Marin.  Aura is an open source framework which can run on many technologies. The way I understand it is that the Lighting Component Framework is a force.com platform specific  implementation/extension of the aura framework. Some elements of lighting are still rather pure aura for which that tag would be more appropriate, but I believe we should also support pure Aura questions.